# Python Flask app logs out when changing directories

Tags: python, flask

I'm building a flask app that uses Google OAuth to login. I can log in no problem but when I change directories to work access different pages in the app the login resets. I'm wondering what I might need to add to keep the user logged in.

```
app
- core
- email
- error pages
- generator
    - views.py
- static
- templates
- users
    - views.py
- main.py
```

The user logs in from users/views.py but when accessing pages from generator/views.py they suddenly get logged out.

```
generator/views.py

from flask import render_template, url_for, flash, redirect, request, Blueprint, session, abort
from flask_login import login_required, current_user
from menutime import db
from menutime.generator.engine import meal_selector, populate_shopping_list
from menutime.models import Meal_Details, Selections

generator = Blueprint('generator',__name__)



@generator.route("/selections", methods=["GET", "POST"])
@login_required
def selections():
    if request.method == "POST":
        # global this_weeks_ids
        global category_selected, desired_servings
        category_selected = []
        category_selected.append(int(request.form["fish_meals"]))
        desired_servings = int(request.form["servings"])
        
        return redirect(url_for('generator.menu'))
    
    return render_template('selections.html')
```

Am I missing something besides @login_required that would indicate who the user is?

I tried adding without any success

@login_manager.user_loader
def load_user(user_id):
return User.get(user_id)

Answer (score 0):

I had app.config["Secret_Key"] set to random, this was causing my issue. Once I changed it to a static variable the site started working properly.